# Users and teams - Many to many relationships Ruby

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a users table and a teams table.
Right now users can only have one team, there's a column in users.team_id.
But now I want to make it possible for users to have multiple teams.
So I already created a user_teams table with user_id and team_id.

I ran migrations like so:

> migrations/create_users_teams

```
class CreateUsersTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_teams do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :team, foreign_key: true, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And my code is as follows:

> models/user.rb

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord

    #belongs_to :team

    # should now have multiple teams
    has_many :user_teams
    has_many :teams, through: :user_teams
```

> models/team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

has_many :user_teams
has_many :users, through: :user_teams
```

> models/user_teams.rb   (new file)

```
class UserTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

From the tutorials I watched that was all I needed to do, but I'm not populating the table. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're trying to populate the table with? Is it using a form?

Comment: @AlecSanger if you could now check nileshkumar's answer, I believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your User_Teams table should have `user_id` and `team_id` columns.

if you have `@user` object with you, then

```
@user.teams << Team.find(some_team_id)
```

This piece of code will automatically create a new row in the User_Teams table with the right `team_id` and `user_id`.

Comment: Yes this seems legit. But now I can't access methods declared in team.rb.
There I have a method called members_and_invites. And I want to access this method in views/overviews/team_members.html.erb , where I have: 
<% current_user.teams.members_and_invites.each do |user| %>
And it gives me:
undefined method `members_and_invites' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

How can I make members_and_invites method available there?

Comment: `current_user.teams` will return a array of teams, how you can call `members_and_invites` instance method on the teams  array? You need to iterate user's teams array to access the method `members_and_invites`

Comment: Your initial answer solved my problem. Now I have other problems but i'll post another questions if I can't find the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`User.in_batches.each_record { |user| UserTeam.create(user: user, team_id: user.team_id) }`

You are going to need to populate the new `UserTeam` table after the migration is completed. You can either do this in the migration itself or via console or a rake task.

After you have populated the UserTeam table you will want to drop the `users.team_id` column.

I would also add `index: true` to both id columns of UserTeam.